# What is the relation between "extensions" and "spec" in Mocha config file?

Tags: javascript, mocha.js

Example configuration: https://github.com/mochajs/mocha/blob/master/example/config/.mocharc.js

Excerpt:

```
module.exports = {
  extension: ['js', 'cjs', 'mjs'],
  spec: ['test/**/*.spec.js'],
};
```

What is the relation between these two options? Option `spec` seems to say "my test files matches the patter `*.spec.js` in any subfolder of `test` folder". What about `extension` then?

Option `extension` alone make sense:

> Mocha discovers test files; when given no files or directories, it finds files with extensions .js, .mjs or .cjs in the test directory (but not its children), relative to the current working directory

... but paired with `spec` it seems just wrong. Why specify `mjs` and then glob only `spec.js`?

I've read https://mochajs.org/#configuring-mocha-nodejs and I find really confusing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These two configurations can be used together or separately.

---

**The `extension` configuration will find test files with matched extensions in the folder that the `spec` option specifies or the default folder(`test`)**

Now, there is a `test` directory contains some test files like this:

```
test
├── a.spec.js
├── b.test.js
├── c.spec.ts
└── d.js
```

**Case 1.**

```js
extension: ['.js', '.cjs'] // or ['js', 'cjs']
```

The `.` is optional, because the mocha will handle it in [`lookupFiles()`](https://github.com/mochajs/mocha/blob/v8.4.0/lib/cli/lookup-files.js#L86) and [`hasMatchingExtname()`](https://github.com/mochajs/mocha/blob/v8.4.0/lib/cli/lookup-files.js#L51) functions use below code.

```js
ext.startsWith('.') ? ext : `.${ext}`
```

Output with debug logs:

```
  mocha:cli:run:helpers files (in order):  [
  '/home/lindu/workspace/expressjs-research/test/a.spec.js',
  '/home/lindu/workspace/expressjs-research/test/b.test.js',
  '/home/lindu/workspace/expressjs-research/test/d.js',
  '/home/lindu/workspace/expressjs-research/test/e.cjs'
] +0ms
  mocha:cli:run:helpers single run with 4 file(s) +3ms


  ✓ should pass a
  ✓ should pass b
  ✓ should pass d
  ✓ should pass e

  4 passing (3ms)
```

It will match the test files with `.js` and `.cjs` extensions in the `test` folder.

**Case 2.**

```js
extension: ['.spec.js']
```

Output with debug logs:

```
  mocha:cli:run:helpers files (in order):  [ '/home/lindu/workspace/expressjs-research/test/a.spec.js' ] +0ms
  mocha:cli:run:helpers single run with 1 file(s) +3ms


  ✓ should pass a

  1 passing (2ms)
```

It will match the test files with the `.spec.js` extension.

Mocha will call `fs.readdirSync('test')` in the `lookupFiles` function to get all files in `test` directory, see [/v8.4.0/lib/cli/lookup-files.js#L113](https://github.com/mochajs/mocha/blob/v8.4.0/lib/cli/lookup-files.js#L113). Then check each pathname if match the `extension` or not use [`hasMatchingExtname()`](https://github.com/mochajs/mocha/blob/v8.4.0/lib/cli/lookup-files.js#L49) function.

**The `spec` option can be files, dirs, and globs to match the test files**. It will be passed to `lookupFiles(filepath, extensions = [], recursive = false)` as the `filepath` argument.

**Case 3.**

Specify test folder to `spec`.

```js
extension: ['.js', '.cjs'],
spec: ['test1'],
```

Debug logs:

```
  mocha:cli:lookup-files looking for files using glob pattern: test1+(.js|.cjs) +0ms
  mocha:cli:run:helpers files (in order):  [] +0ms
Error: No test files found: "test1"
```

**Case 4.**

Use a glob for `spec`

```js
spec: ['test/**/*.spec.js']
```

This is equivalent to `extension: ['.spec.js']`.

Debug logs:

```
  mocha:cli:run:helpers files (in order):  [ '/home/lindu/workspace/expressjs-research/test/a.spec.js' ] +0ms
  mocha:cli:run:helpers single run with 1 file(s) +5ms


  ✓ should pass a

  1 passing (2ms)
```

The `lookupFiles()` function will use [`glob.hasMagic(filepath)`](https://github.com/mochajs/mocha/blob/v8.4.0/lib/cli/lookup-files.js#L80) to check if the value of `spec` option contains any "magic" glob characters. What are "magic" glob characters? See [`hasMagic`](https://github.com/isaacs/node-glob#hasmagicpattern-string--string-options-globoptions--boolean) and [hasMagic test cases](https://github.com/isaacs/node-glob/blob/v10.3.0/test/has-magic.ts).

A pattern like `test/**/*.spec.js` contains the magic glob character '*'. Then `lookupFiles()` function return all files that match this glob.

**Case 5.**

Use specific test files for `spec`.

```js
spec: ['test/a.spec.js', 'test/b.test.js'],
```

Debug logs:

```
  mocha:cli:run:helpers files (in order):  [
  '/home/lindu/workspace/expressjs-research/test/a.spec.js',
  '/home/lindu/workspace/expressjs-research/test/b.test.js'
] +0ms
  mocha:cli:run:helpers single run with 2 file(s) +2ms


  ✓ should pass a
  ✓ should pass b

  2 passing (2ms)
```

You can turn on debug logs for the `cli` module of mocha:

```
DEBUG=mocha:cli:run:helpers,mocha:cli:lookup-files mocha
```

Read and debug the source code for knowing more details.

Comment: Thanks, great answer. So the official example is wrong, based on your cases? Because it specify the spec not as a folder but as a glob match, but extension still show "js", "cjs", "mjs"?

Comment: @gremo Official example is not wrong. But the basic example just shows all possible configurations and a part of values they accept, not all possible values.

Comment: If I understand you anwser, the official example say: look for any file ending with 'js', 'cjs', 'mjs' in the folder `test/**/*.spec.js`, but folder is a glob, then it would only consider `.spec.js` as test files, ignoring `.spec.mjs`

Comment: @gremo Correct, please see case 4, the `glob.hasMagic(filepath)` will check the `spec` . If it's glob, the `extensions` will be ignored.